# how to disable source button in ckeditor 4

Tags: ckeditor, toolbar

I am using ckeditor version 4 as text editor in my website for user but I want my website secure, so that's why I want to disable the ckeditor source button... so that user cannot add any kind of code in my website.

ckeditor `config.js` file is by default empty; what is the setting for custom toolbar?

This is the file where I am using ckeditor:

```
<textarea name="article_content" id="article_content" rows="5" cols="50" style="width:90%; margin-bottom:15px;"></textarea>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            CKEDITOR.replace( 'article_content',
            {
filebrowserBrowseUrl :'<?php echo base_url(); ?>asset/ckeditor/filemanager/browser/default/browser.html?Connector=<?php echo base_url(); ?>asset/ckeditor/filemanager/connectors/php/connector.php',
filebrowserImageBrowseUrl : '<?php echo base_url(); ?>asset/ckeditor/filemanager/browser/default/browser.html?Type=Image&Connector=<?php echo base_url(); ?>asset/ckeditor/filemanager/connectors/php/connector.php',
filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl :'<?php echo base_url(); ?>asset/ckeditor/filemanager/browser/default/browser.html?Type=Flash&Connector=<?php echo base_url(); ?>asset/ckeditor/filemanager/connectors/php/connector.php',
filebrowserUploadUrl  :'<?php echo base_url(); ?>asset/ckeditor/filemanager/connectors/php/upload.php?Type=File',
filebrowserImageUploadUrl : '<?php echo base_url(); ?>asset/ckeditor/filemanager/connectors/php/upload.php?Type=Image',
filebrowserFlashUploadUrl : '<?php echo base_url(); ?>asset/ckeditor/filemanager/connectors/php/upload.php?Type=Flash'
                });
            </script>
```

Does anybody know how to customize the toolbar?

Comment: http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Toolbar, Simply remove `source` item from array of toolbar config.

Answer (score 16):

Either by:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'article_content', {
    removePlugins: 'sourcearea',
    // The rest of options...
} );
```

Or:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'article_content', {
    removeButtons: 'Source',
    // The rest of options...
} );
```

You can also redefine toolbar completely by using [`config.toolbar`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-toolbar). Read more about it in the [Toolbar Customization Guide](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_toolbar).

Comment: Thank you. I swear CKEditor is really powerful but their documentation and samples really suck ass. Some of the worst I've ever seen.

Comment: We are working on this very hard and in couple of weeks/months the situation will be improved. The problem is the size x complexity of the project - full documentation would have to be enormous and there are simply not enough resources to do it quickly.

Answer (score 11):

You can remove any button from CKeditor toolbar by using config.removeButton command. Write this line in your config.js file

```
config.removeButtons = 'Source';
```

if you want to remove multiple items do this

> config.removeButtons =
>   'Anchor,Subscript,Superscript,Strikethrough,Source';